# Serialize object as Map instead of String using Jackson databind?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jackson-databind

Normally one does something like this when you want to serialize an object to a JSON string:

```java
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
```

I wonder if it's possible to serialize an object directly into a `java.util.Map` instead of a String? I.e. something like this (pseudo code):

```java
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAs(myObject, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>() {});
```

I know I can serialize the object to a String first and then deserialize it as a `Map<String,Object>` but I'm asking if there's is a way to do this *without* first serializing to a String?

I'm using Jackson 2.11.1.

Comment: You may be having a bit of trouble finding search results because serialization is, by definition, conversion into a single stream of bytes, such as a `String` or `byte[]`, not a structured object like a `Map`. As shown in the answer, you're looking for just a "conversion".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [convertValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-) method of ObjectMapper to convert Object into Map

```
Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.convertValue(myObject, Map.class);
```

Comment: There's also an overloaded variant of `convertValue` available that takes a `TypeReference` as parameter instead of `Class`, allowing to avoid the unchecked assignment warning due to the raw type.